# Distance from $x$ point to $A$ equal $0$, when $x \in A$ and $d(x, A) - d(x, B) = 0$, when $x \in A \cap B$.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

> Let $A \subset X$ and $x \in A$, then $d(x, A) = 0.$

I'm trying to figure out why this is true? If I consider a simple example and let $A= (0,1)$ and pick $x= \frac12$ then $$d(\frac12, (0,1) ) = \inf_{y\in(0,1)} d(\frac12, y)$$ but I'm not sure why this infimum evaluates to $0$?

> Let $A, B \subset X$ be non-empty. And if $A \cap B \ne \emptyset$,  then for $x \in A\cap B$ we have $d(x, A) - d(x, B) = 0 \implies d(x,A) = d(x,B)$.

Similarly here if I consider $A=[0,1]$ and $B=[\frac12, 2]$, then $A\cap B=[\frac12, 1]$ and picking $x \in A\cap B$ to be for example $x = \frac34$ then how is $$\inf_{x\in[0,1]}d(\frac34, [0,1]) = \inf_{y \in [\frac12, 2]} d(\frac34, [\frac12, 2])?$$

I've been trying to find proofs for this but couldn't find any...

Comment: Let $y=\frac{1}{2}$ we have $d(\frac{1}{2},y)=0$, so the infimum is $0$.

Answer (score 1):

**Point 1**

If $x \in A$, then as a distance is non-negative and $d(y,y)=0$ for all $y \in X$, you get that $d(x,A)=0$.

**Point 2**

If $x \in A \cap B$ then as a consequence of point 1, $d(x,A)=0=d(x,B)$.

Answer (score 0):

All distances are $\ge 0$ so $0$ is always a lower bound for $D:=\{d(x,y)\mid y \in A\}$. In this case $0$ is an element of the set as $D \ni d(x, \frac12)=0$, so $0 = \inf D = d(x,A)$.

So if $x \in A\cap B$ then $d(x,A)= 0 =d(x,B)$ by the same reasoning.